Kinetic energy in circular motion with friction
Suppose a mass $m$ is positioned at the tip center of 1/2-circle with radius $R$ s.t the initial speed and angle both satisfy $v_{i}, \theta_i = 0$ respectively and it falls down to the ground in the right direction (which that $0 \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ increases).
Let $\theta_0$ be the angle at which the mass would "detach" the circle during its fall (which is when the normal force applied on the mass is zero), assuming no friction between the mass and the circle's surface.
Now, intuitively if there was friction between the mass and circle, I'd expect that the mass would detach in a larger angle $\theta_1$ which satisfies $\theta_0 < \theta_1$. However, I struggle to see how it links to the work done by the gravitational force: If there was friction, some of the potential energy would be transferred to heat (.i.e friction is non-conserving) and then the kinetic energy at each moment would be lesser, hence the speed would be lesser. But how can I use this intuition to reason the inequality between the angles?

Remark: I'm asking this question for my own understanding, this wasnt a part of an exercise but I'm trying to understand the dynamics further

The mass will remain in contact with the sphere so long as the inward radial force needed to keep the object moving in a circle is less than or equal to the radial component of gravity.  Beyond this point, there is insufficient centripetal force on the object, and it will leave the sphere.  In other words, we must have
$$
\frac{mv^2}{r} \leq m g \cos \theta.
$$
Consider $v$ to be a function of $\theta$.  If $v(\theta)$ is less than the value that it would have in the absence of friction, then there will be some range of values of $\theta$ which will violate this inequality in the absence of friction but satisfy this inequality in the presence of friction.  This means that the mass will stay on the sphere for longer.

Can you guide me to the intuition which there has to be such range of $\theta$? I might only see this mathematically (by monotonocity) but that doesn't click to me physically

@X4J:  One way to see this is to think about the angle $\theta_0$ at which the mass would leave the sphere in the absence of friction.  At that same angle in the presence of friction, the mass will be moving at a slower speed;  so it can stay in contact with the sphere at the angle $\theta_0$, and must leave the sphere at a greater angle $\theta > \theta_0$.
